# how to pass either a @input label prop or the content as label to a angular button component?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a label that can come to the component as an @Input() or as content to a button:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button[app-button]',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngIf="label">
    <ng-content>{{label}}</ng-content>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!label">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-container>
  `,
})
```

Problem is that the above does work because ng-content can not have content.
Any ideas how to solve this without wrapping the button in another host element?

EDIT: I would like to use it as follows.

```html
<!-- this should work -->
<button app-button>I am a label</button>
<!-- this also should work -->
<button app-button label="Another label"></button>
<!-- should work -->
<button app-button [label]="'Wow a Label'"></button>
```

Comment: Why do you need `ng-content` in the first case? Can't you just use a `div`?

Comment: I could wrap it in a div, just want to know if it is possible without extra host element wrapper.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand the question then. Can you show us the two different usages of your component and the approximate resulting html you want to have? Or make a Stackblitz to show what you want?

Comment: added some examples of how the component would be used.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want??

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button[app-button]',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngIf="label">
      {{label}
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!label">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-container>
  `,
})
```

Comment: That way the label content does not go as the button child.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is not a `Component`, but a `Directive`. If you provide an attribute selector the provided template will be ignored. Inside your `Directive` you can get access to the host element via `ElementRef`. So what you want, could be implemented like this:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'button[app-button]',
})
export class ButtonDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  label: string;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.label) {
      this.el.nativeElement.innerText = this.label;
    }
  }
}
```

You could also take a look at the documentation for [attribute directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives). If you need to modify the host element you could also look into [structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives).

That being said, this doesn't feel like the angular way to do things. I would consider just building an `<app-button></app-button>` component with this feature.

Comment: yes, I have indeed been fighting with the framework because most of the components I create in other companies are either coming from a design system, or we create with html in mind and html does not care about this wrapping unless I want webcomponents or dom encapsulation. But that was the way angular choose to implement and it is kinda of a pain when you are counting that your html will have no wrapping between two specific elements.